# How do i make a string temporarily appear for 10 seconds then dissapear

Tags: java, android, string

Im using eclipse and making an android app and need to make a string appear for 10 seconds and then dissapear.

Comment: Set a timer for 10 seconds and set the text view to invisible or gone when it goes off.

Comment: And what have you done so far?

Comment: well i need it to be on the click of a button

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_textview_id);
textView.setText("some text");
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}, 10 * 1000); // start this function after a delay of 10 seconds
```